# Принято ли использовать несколько контроллеров для работы с одной моделью?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Есть модель Order. Она отвечает за работу с заказами. Необходимо сделать часть сайта для пользователей, а часть сайта для администратора.
Вопрос в том, стоит ли создавать отдельный контроллер для обработки запросов пользователя, и отдельный для работы администратора. Ибо для одного контроллера будет много похожих функций, сложно будет ориентироваться. Использование разных контроллеров для этого звучит вполне логично.
Если так стоит сделать, как стоит называть в таком случае контроллеры?

Comment: ну, я  делаю контроллер и модель для пользователей, а админские их расширяют, добавляя, например, методы записи данных

Comment: @ColoredAnt всё лолгично, как по мне. Просто разделите логику админки и морды на уровне папок (admin, storefront). Если много одинаковостей, просто перенесите их в абстракцию и наследуйтесь от неё (ща может начаться холивар :p)